# Prove that dim(M∩N)=dim(N)−1

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let L be a vector space of dimension $ n $ and  $ M,N \subset $ L linear subspaces such that $ dim(M)=n-1 $ and $ N \not \subset M $.

Prove that $ dim( M \, \cap N ) = dim(N) -1 $

**My attempt:**

Let $ (v_1,...,v_{n-1}) $ be a basis for $ M $ , we'll expand the basis of $ M $ to basis of $ M + N $ by the vectors $ (v_n,...,v_t) $ so that the basis of $ M + N $ is $ (v_1,...,v_t) $.
Since $ M + N \subseteq V $ then $ dim(M + N) \leq dim(V) $ , so that
$ n-1 \leq dim(M+N) = t \leq n $.
**[ I dont know how to continue from here ]**

Basically I want to use the dimension theorem for subspaces $ dim(M+N) = dim(M) + dim(N) - dim(M \cap N)$ But I got stuck and don't know how to continue, can you please help?

Edit:

As shown in the answers below, after showing that $ dim( M + N ) = n $ then, using the dimension theorem,
$ dim(M+N) = dim(M) + dim(N) - dim(M \cap N) \iff $ $ dim(M \cap N) = dim(M) + dim(N) - dim(M+N) \iff $ $ dim(M \cap N) = n-1 + dim(N) - n \iff dim(M \cap N) = dim(N) - 1  $ . And we've finished the proof.

Comment: If subspace $M$ has a basis $\{v_1,\dots,v_{n-1}\}$ but there exists some $w\in N$ that is not an element of $M$, what can you conclude about the set $\{v_1,\dots, v_{n-1}, w\}$? Are the elements in this set linearly independent?

Comment: Since $ w $ cannot be spanned by $ \{v_1,\dots,v_{n-1}\} $, and we know $ \{v_1,\dots,v_{n-1}\} $ are linearly independent, therefore the whole set $ \{v_1,\dots,v_{n-1},w\} $ is linearly independent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there! Take a basis $(v_1, \dots, v_{n-1})$ of $M$. Since $N$ is not included in $M$, then you can take a vector $v_n \in N \backslash M$. This vector does not belong to the span of $(v_1, \dots, v_{n-1})$ (which is $M$), so the family $(v_1, \dots, v_n)$ is linearly independent. This gives a linearly independent family of size $n$ in $M+N$, and therefore $\dim(M+N) \geq n$, and it cannot be more than the dimension of the space, so $\dim(M+N) = n$. Finally, conclude with the dimension formula.

Answer (score 2):

If $\dim(M+N) = \dim(M)$, then since $M \subset M+N$, we have $M = M+N \supset N$ (contradicting $N \not\subset M$)

Therefore $\dim(M+N) > \dim(M) = n-1,$ which along with $\dim(M+N) \leq n$ implies $\dim(M+N) = n$.

Now finish by the dimension theorem.